# Showing $|S_n/\sqrt{n}|^\alpha$ is uniformly integrable given certain conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-integrability

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. with $E(X_1)=0$ and $E(X_1^4)<\infty.$ Let $S_n=X_1+\dots +X_n$. Show that $|S_n/\sqrt{n}|^\alpha$ are uniformly integrable for any $0<\alpha<4$.

I am trying to answer the above problem. I know that I want to show that:
$$
\lim\limits_{M\rightarrow \infty}\left[\sup\limits_n E\left( \left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|^\alpha 1_{\{\left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|^\alpha >M\}} \right)  \right]=0.
$$

I also know that it would be enough to show that:
$$
\sup\limits_n E\left( \left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|^\alpha \right)<\infty
$$

But I don't really see what sort of manipulations or tricks to use to show either one of these statements.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it is sufficient to show that (what you wrote probably was a typo.)
$$\sup_n E\left(\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^4\right) < \infty. \tag{1}$$
Since
\begin{align*}
S_n^4 = (X_1 + \ldots + X_n)^4 = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^4 + \sum_{i \neq j} X_i^2 X_j^2 + R
\end{align*}
where $R$ denotes other terms whose expectations are $0$. Notice that there are $3n(n - 1)$ terms with the form $X_i^2 X_j^2$, whence
$$E(S_n^4) = nE(X_1^4) + 3n(n - 1)E(X_1^2X_2^2).$$
Consequently,
$$ E\left(\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^4\right) = \frac{1}{n}E(X_1^4)  + \frac{3(n - 1)}{n} E(X_1^2X_2^2) \leq E(X_1^4) + 3E(X_1^2X_2^2) < \infty,$$
from which $(1)$ holds, and thus the sequence is uniformly integrable.

Comment: can you explain how we know that there are $3n(n-1)$ terms with the form $X_i^2 X_j^2$?

Comment: It is a combinatoric problem, think it over.